# Detecting user-initiated element resizing (as distinct from document flow resizing)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, resize

I desire an iframe that takes all available space horizontally, and automatically resizes itself vertically to fit its content (including on content change or window resizing), but is also manually resizable by the user, using the CSS property `resize: both`. The purpose is embedding a design, with it filling the available space by default, but also letting the user see how it works at different screen sizes.

The iframe is from the same origin, so there are no security problems—the parent window can do whatever it likes with `iframe.contentDocument`.

Automatically resizing the iframe to fit its contents is straightforward:

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<h1>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy doggerel."
        style="width:calc(100% - 2px);border:1px solid black"
        onload="
    recalculate = () => {
        this.style.height = this.contentDocument.documentElement.offsetHeight + 'px';
    }
    new ResizeObserver(recalculate).observe(this.contentDocument.documentElement);
    recalculate();
"></iframe>
```

<sup><sup>(Wow, that HTML syntax highlighting really fell apart there! Also, no proper “snippet” here because the CSP seems to break `contentDocument` access.)</sup></sup>

And making a user-resizable iframe is straightforward:

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<h1>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy doggerel."
        style="resize:both"></iframe>
```

… but these techniques don’t combine well, because resizing as a user comes through in just the same way as resizing due to window size changes and the likes, so as soon as the user resizes it, the auto-height code kicks in and ignores the height they just specified.

So if the user manually resizes the iframe, I want my auto-resizing to disconnect the ResizeObserver.

Is there any way I can distinguish a resize due to user action (resizing the iframe via the corner grippy) from a resize due to environmental change (content change within the iframe, or layout change without the iframe, including viewport resize)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you resize manually, `element.style.{width, height}` get set. So one solution is for auto-sizing to not use those properties, but to set the width and height in some other way, so that you can distinguish the values.

For `width`, that’s easy, because the auto-sizing only sets `height`: if `width` is set (or, if you set a value like `calc(100% - 2px)`, set to something other than that), disconnect auto-sizing.

For height? That’s harder, but two techniques have occurred to me:

1. Set the height in a separate stylesheet (so that `element.style.height` is not set at all), and keep on updating the text of that style element.
2. Use `height: var(--height)`, and set `--height` to the actual value. That way `element.style.height` won’t change unless user resizing occurs. I recommend this technique as it’s a little easier to reason about and I suspect it may be a tad faster (though I haven’t tested that at all).

```html
<style>
iframe {
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    border: 1px solid black;
    resize: both;
}
</style>
<iframe srcdoc="<h1>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy doggerel."
        style="height:var(--height)"
        onload="
    recalculate = () => {
        // (var(--height) could just as easily be shifted to the stylesheet,
        // but I’m demonstrating a point here in how it can be done.)
        if (this.style.width || this.style.height !== 'var(--height)') {
            // User resizing has occurred.
            if (observer) {
                observer.disconnect();
            }
            return;
        }
        this.style.setProperty('--height', this.contentDocument.documentElement.offsetHeight + 'px');
    }
    var observer = window.ResizeObserver && new ResizeObserver(recalculate);
    if (observer) {
        observer.observe(this.contentDocument.documentElement);
    }
    recalculate();
"></iframe>
```